# Getting internal null pointer with SolrJ API

Tags: java, apache, solr, solrj, solrcloud

I am attempting to add docs to solr. In this process, I am getting this exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.CloudSolrServer.condenseResponse(CloudSolrServer.java:442) ~[solr-solrj-4.8.1.jar:4.8.1 1594670 - rmuir - 2014-05-14 19:38:42]
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.CloudSolrServer.directUpdate(CloudSolrServer.java:398) ~[solr-solrj-4.8.1.jar:4.8.1 1594670 - rmuir - 2014-05-14 19:38:42]
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.CloudSolrServer.request(CloudSolrServer.java:510) ~[solr-solrj-4.8.1.jar:4.8.1 1594670 - rmuir - 2014-05-14 19:38:42]
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.request.AbstractUpdateRequest.process(AbstractUpdateRequest.java:124) ~[solr-solrj-4.8.1.jar:4.8.1 1594670 - rmuir - 2014-05-14 19:38:42]
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServer.add(SolrServer.java:116) ~[solr-solrj-4.8.1.jar:4.8.1 1594670 - rmuir - 2014-05-14 19:38:42]
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServer.add(SolrServer.java:102) ~[solr-solrj-4.8.1.jar:4.8.1 1594670 - rmuir - 2014-05-14 19:38:42]
```

The null pointer seems to be triggered from inside the API.

**Code to upload doc:**

```
UpdateResponse res = cloudSolrServer.add(tagDoc, 5000);
status = parseResponse(res);
```

**parseResponseMethod:**

```
InputStream is = (InputStream) res.getResponse().get("stream");
XMLResponseParser parser = new XMLResponseParser();
NamedList<Object> nl = parser.processResponse(is, "UTF-8");
NamedList<Object> responseHeader = (NamedList) nl.get("responseHeader");
status = (int) responseHeader.get("status");        
return status == 0;
```

**Code to initialize CloudSolrServer instance:**

```
CloudSolrServer cloudSolrServer = new CloudSolrServer(zkhost);
cloudSolrServer.setDefaultCollection(collectionName);
cloudSolrServer.setParser(null);
cloudSolrServer.setZkClientTimeout(60000);
cloudSolrServer.setZkConnectTimeout(60000);
cloudSolrServer.connect();
```

What could be the reasons for this exception? How can it be resolved?